# the hidden field inside for loop is returning only the last value

Tags: php

```
 <form action="" method="post">
     <?php
       $abc = 10;
       for($key=1;$key<=30;$key++)
         {
     ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" value="<?php echo $key;?>" />
            <textarea name="vids" rows="4" cols="50"><?php echo $abc; ?>      </textarea>
     <?php
           $abc++;
         }
     ?>
       <input type="submit" name="abc" />
      </form>
```

The above code is returning only the last value of the textarea and hidden field.
I want to get the the hidden field value for the textarea updated along with the updated value of the textarea.

Please help me with the solution.

Comment: check demo: https://eval.in/682416

Comment: If you want multiple input/textareas with the same name, you need to add `[]` after the names, like this: `name="hidden_id[]"`. Then you will get an array with the fields. Otherwise, you will only get the value of the last generated field. The same goes for: `name="vids[]"`.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to change `name="hidden_id"` to `name="hidden_id[]"` and `name="vids"` to `name="vids[]"` . Then them can hold multiple values. When you submit the form `hidden_id[]`, `vids[]` will return arrays. Therefor you have to loop them for access one by one.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['abc'])){ 
    // $_POST['hidden_id'] return as a array
    if(!empty($_POST['hidden_id'])){
        foreach ($_POST['hidden_id'] as $id) {
            echo $id;
        }
    }

    // access textarea values
    if(!empty($_POST['vids'])){
        foreach ($_POST['vids'] as $text) {
            echo $text;
        }
    }

}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
     <?php
       $abc = 10;
       for($key=1;$key<=30;$key++)
         {
     ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_id[]" value="<?php echo $key;?>" />
            <textarea name="vids[]" rows="4" cols="50"><?php echo $abc; ?></textarea>
     <?php
           $abc++;
         }
     ?>
   <input type="submit" name="abc"  value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem lies on the input's name which are name="hidden_id" and name="vids".
You should change them into name="hidden_id[]" and name="vids[]" in order for them to hold multiple values. Please see the code below

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" value="<?php echo $key;?>"/>
<textarea name="vids" rows="4" cols="50"><?php echo $abc; ?></textarea>
```